# How to add SharpShell extensions at a specific position

Tags: c#, contextmenu, sharpshell

I'm adding some extensions to the contextmenu by using sharpshell. Yet I cannot see any option to specify the posion where these extensions appear in the contextmenu.

So I would like to know, if there is a possibility to define at which positon the extension is added to the contextmenu. 
eg. my extensions appear on the top of the menulist, but I want them to be right about the "propperties"-entry.

Best regards
Boba